# Why is not printing user input in NetBeans console? Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I need to print user input in my console (Javafx NetBeans).

This is my code, and strangely is only printing the label name: "Address". Earlier when I only had 2 fields it would only print the last entry, and it would not print the first entry by user when button pressed.

How can I print all the input from user in console?

```
    package customerentry2;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 *
 * @author 718358
 */

public class CustomerEntry2 extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

       @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Customer Entry");

        Label nameLabel = new Label("First Name: ");
        Label nameLabel2 = new Label("Last Name: ");
        Label addressInput = new Label("Address: ");
        TextField nameInput = new TextField();
        TextField nameInput2 = new TextField();
        TextField addressInput3 = new TextField();
        button = new Button("Save");
        button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(nameInput.getText()));
        button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(nameInput2.getText()));
        button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(addressInput3.getText()));
        //Layout
        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, nameInput, nameLabel2, nameInput2, addressInput, addressInput3,  button);

        scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


}
```

Comment: Your `Label` is named `addressInput`, and you do `addressInput.getText()`. The `TextField` is named `addressInput3`.

Comment: @resueman: thanks! I edited code, and now is printing input from third text field, but is still not printing the input from first 2 fields, how can I print input from all 3 fields?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because each time you call `setOnAction` it *replaces* the existing `EventHandler`, rather than adding an additional one. There's two ways you can fix this.

You can either take care of all three `println`s in one `EventHandler`, like this:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {System.out.println(nameInput.getText());
                         System.out.println(nameInput2.getText()));
                         System.out.println(addressInput3.getText());
                        });
```

Or you can use `addEventHandler` to add more `EventHandler`s to the button without replacing the existing ones. That would look like this:

```
button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,
                       (ActionEvent e) -> System.out.println(nameInput.getText()));
button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,
                       (ActionEvent e) -> System.out.println(nameInput2.getText()));
button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,
                       (ActionEvent e) -> System.out.println(addressInput3.getText()));
```

Either one should work for you. The first one is a little shorter and easier to read, but the second way is more flexible if you plan to dynamically add and remove the handlers.

Comment: thanks a lot! this solved the issue. Have a great day!